# Ng-Model on a button

Tags: angularjs

I have this line of code, I have tried using the value="" which didn't work.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="colorScheme = '123'" ng-model="eventData.theme">Theme 123</button>
```

I have stuff binding to the database. For example a `title` text being placed into my binding under `eventData.title`

I want `123` to be placed inside the binding so it can be submitted to the DB.
Thanks

Comment: with what property you want to bind the title property? Can you explain it a bit more.

Comment: I'm not i'm wanting to bind the value of the button, The title was just an example of how i've done it with the title field :)

Comment: value ='{{eventData.title}}' should work then

Comment: who are going to set value for `eventData.theme`

Comment: it'll just be done on the button click, So i have `value="123"` on the button and that would be sent into the binding on click of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML CODE:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="colorScheme(123)" ng-model="eventData.theme">Theme 123</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.eventData = {};
$scope.colorScheme = function(number){
    $scope.eventData.title = number;
};
```

Comment: This didn't work, I have firelds in the event data already if thats an issue

Comment: you just want to pass '123' on button click to controller right?

Comment: i believe so, i have an app js with scope.eventData = { theme: null, } at the moment, I could do with it changing to the 123 that the button has (baring in mind the button currently changing the color scheme of the site, so the ng-click cant really be changed